# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, jquery, html, console

We have tried to do a checkout on our website but its not working. When looking into the console, it says the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

and its pointing the below line

```
jQuery(".menus > ul").before("<div class=\"barshw\"><a class=\"iconsclick\" onclick=\"show(this)\"><i class=\"fa fa-bars hideicon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></div><div class=\"contentbody\"><div class=\"contentmenu\" onclick=\"stop_propogate(event)\"><div class=\"itm\">"+document.querySelector('.menu-container .menus').innerHTML+"</div>");
```

when comment this line, we can do checkout.

Now how can resolve this error without commenting this line. Because if i comment the line, other functionality(megamenu) is not working.

Below is the full code in script file:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "lgsign"
],
        function ($, lgsign) {


           // Use the conventional $ prefix for variables that hold jQuery objects.
var $slider2;

// If the only purpose of the windowWidth() function is to set the slide variables,
// it can be renamed and rewritten to supply the full configuration object instead.
function buildSliderConfiguration2() {
  // When possible, you should cache calls to jQuery functions to improve performance.
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var numberOfVisibleSlides;

  if (windowWidth < 420) {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 1;
  }
  else if (windowWidth < 768) {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 1;
  }
  else if (windowWidth < 1200) {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 3;
  }
  else {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 3;
  }

  return {
    pager: true,
    controls: false,
    auto: true,
    slideWidth: 5000,
    startSlide: 0,
    nextText: ' ',
    prevText: ' ',
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 20,
    minSlides: numberOfVisibleSlides,
    maxSlides: numberOfVisibleSlides
  };
}

// This function can be called either to initialize the slider for the first time
// or to reload the slider when its size changes.
function configureSlider2() {
  var config = buildSliderConfiguration2();

  if ($slider2 && $slider2.reloadSlider) {
    // If the slider has already been initialized, reload it.
    $slider2.reloadSlider(config);
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise, initialize the slider.
    $slider2 = $('.explore-slider').bxSlider(config);
  }
}

$('.slider-prev').click(function () {
  var current = $slider2.getCurrentSlide();
  $slider2.goToPrevSlide(current) - 1;
});
$('.slider-next').click(function () {
  var current = $slider2.getCurrentSlide();
  $slider2.goToNextSlide(current) + 1;
});

// Configure the slider every time its size changes.
$(window).on("orientationchange resize", configureSlider2);
// Configure the slider once on page load.
configureSlider2();



// Use the conventional $ prefix for variables that hold jQuery objects.
var $slider1;

// If the only purpose of the windowWidth() function is to set the slide variables,
// it can be renamed and rewritten to supply the full configuration object instead.
function buildSliderConfiguration1() {
  // When possible, you should cache calls to jQuery functions to improve performance.
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var numberOfVisibleSlides;

  if (windowWidth < 420) {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 1;
  }
  else if (windowWidth < 768) {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 1;
  }
  else if (windowWidth < 1200) {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 1;
  }
  else {
    numberOfVisibleSlides = 1;
  }

  return {
    pager: true,
    controls: false,
    auto: true,
    slideWidth: 5000,
    startSlide: 0,
    nextText: ' ',
    prevText: ' ',
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 20,
    minSlides: numberOfVisibleSlides,
    maxSlides: numberOfVisibleSlides
  };
}

// This function can be called either to initialize the slider for the first time
// or to reload the slider when its size changes.
function configureSlider1() {
  var config = buildSliderConfiguration1();

  if ($slider1 && $slider1.reloadSlider) {
    // If the slider has already been initialized, reload it.
    $slider1.reloadSlider(config);
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise, initialize the slider.
    $slider1 = $('.washing-slider').bxSlider(config);
  }
}

$('.slider-prev').click(function () {
  var current = $slider1.getCurrentSlide();
  $slider1.goToPrevSlide(current) - 1;
});
$('.slider-next').click(function () {
  var current = $slider1.getCurrentSlide();
  $slider1.goToNextSlide(current) + 1;
});

// Configure the slider every time its size changes.
$(window).on("orientationchange resize", configureSlider1);
// Configure the slider once on page load.
configureSlider1();



/** menu tab footer script**/


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".menu").click(function(){
    jQuery(".navbar").toggle();
  });

  jQuery(".footer-arrow").click(function(){
    jQuery(".footer-bottom-innr").toggle();
  });

  jQuery(".tab-cl").click(function(){
    var clid=jQuery(this).attr("id");
  var id=clid.split("-");
  jQuery(".offer-tab-con").hide();
  jQuery(".tab-cl").removeClass("active");
  jQuery("#tabcon-"+id[1]).show();
  jQuery("#cl-"+id[1]).addClass("active");

  });

});



/*** toggle nav **/


/***** Home page tab  ****/

jQuery('#tabs li a').click(function(){
  var t = jQuery(this).attr('id');

  if(jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive')){ //this is the start of our condition 
    jQuery('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');           
    jQuery(this).removeClass('inactive');

    jQuery('.container').hide();
    jQuery('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
 }
});


/*** Acton Calculator ****/

jQuery(".arrow").click(function(){     
     jQuery(".action-calculator-body").toggleClass("calculator-full");  
     jQuery(".arrow-close").css({'z-index':'99','display':'block'});
     jQuery(".arrow").hide(); 
});

  jQuery(".arrow-close").click(function(){
    jQuery(".action-calculator-body").toggleClass("calculator-full");
    jQuery(".arrow").show();
    jQuery(".arrow-close").hide();
  });




/**** Compare product ****/
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".collaps-all").click(function(){
    jQuery(".sub-catagory-outer").toggle();
  });
  jQuery(".catagory-main-title").click(function(){
    jQuery(".sub-catagory-outer").toggle();
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("arrow-open");
  });

 /* jQuery(".arrow").click(function(){
    jQuery(".action-calculator-body").toggleClass("calculator-full");
  }); */

});

jQuery('body').on('click','.sub-catagory-title',function(){

  jQuery(this).closest('table').toggleClass('hidden-area');

})

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

     //>=, not <=
    if (scroll >= 300) {
        //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
        jQuery(".compare-pro-list").addClass("com-fixed");
    jQuery(".fixed-com-print").addClass("com-fixed");
    jQuery(".compare-item-info").addClass("com-fixed");
    }else if(scroll < 300) {
        //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
        jQuery(".compare-pro-list").removeClass("com-fixed");
    jQuery(".fixed-com-print").removeClass("com-fixed");
    jQuery(".compare-item-info").removeClass("com-fixed");
    }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      "use strict";
      jQuery('.itm > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
      jQuery('.itm > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
      jQuery(".menus > ul").before("<div class=\"barshw\"><a class=\"iconsclick\" onclick=\"show(this)\"><i class=\"fa fa-bars hideicon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></div><div class=\"contentbody\"><div class=\"contentmenu\" onclick=\"stop_propogate(event)\"><div class=\"itm\">"+document.querySelector('.menu-container .menus').innerHTML+"</div>");

      jQuery('.contentmenu  ul li:has( > ul)').each(function(){ 
                          if(jQuery(this).find('a i').length == 0){ 
                                  jQuery(this).find('a')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>'); 
                          } 
                  });
      document.querySelectorAll('.contentmenu .u_cat_image').forEach(function(e_im){
        e_im.closest('li').remove();
      });

      jQuery(".menus > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
        if (jQuery(window).width() > 943) {
          var el = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li' ? e.target : e.target.closest('li');
          if(el.querySelector('ul li') != undefined){
            jQuery(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            setTimeout(function(){
              var el = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li' ? e.target : e.target.closest('li');
              var sty = el.querySelector('ul').style.display;
              if(sty == 'block'){
                el.querySelectorAll('.menus > ul > li > ul').forEach(function(se){
                  se.style.display = 'flex';
                });
              }
            }, 160);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      });
      jQuery("li:has( > ul)").each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).find('i').length > 0){
        jQuery(this).find('i')[0].addEventListener('click', function(ev){
          if (jQuery(window).width() <= 943) {
              ev.preventDefault();
              ev.stopPropagation();
              jQuery(ev.target).closest('li').children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
           }
        })
       }
     });


      document.querySelector('.contentmenu').style.left = - (document.querySelector('.contentmenu').clientWidth + 300) + 'px';
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
      jQuery(".itm > ul > li").children("ul").hide();
      jQuery(".itm > ul").removeClass('show-on-mobile');
    });


// jQuery(function(){
// jQuery(".menus > ul > li > ul").css('height','auto');
// });


   });




function show(e){
      var att = e.getAttribute('active');
      if(att == undefined || att == "false"){
        e.setAttribute('active', 'true');
        document.querySelector('.contentmenu').style.left = "26px";
        setTimeout(function(){
          document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', close_menu);
        }, 100);
      }else{
        e.setAttribute('active', 'false');
        document.querySelector('body').removeEventListener('click', close_menu);
        document.querySelector('.contentmenu').style.left = - (document.querySelector('.contentmenu').clientWidth + 120) + 'px';
      }
    }
    function close_menu(){
      document.querySelector('.iconsclick').click();
    }
    function stop_propogate(ev){
      ev.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$(".menu-container .menus").get(0)` instead of `document.querySelector('.menu-container .menus')` if you have Jquery already defined
And also check if this element exists

Comment: Still, it says error: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: As i know there is no menu in default Luma theme on checkout page